# How to place caption on center of figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, pdftex, captions, alignment

The following code creates a figure environment, creates a tikz environment inside, draws a line, closes it then captions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A line.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The caption is in the middle of the whole page. Is it possible to make it so that the caption is on the center of the figure instead?

Comment: Do you mean the `\caption` should overlap the `tikzpicture` of yours and be placed in its centre?

Comment: Your image is left aligned in `figure` float, but caption is centered. Try to insert `\centering` after `\begin{figure`. Does result of this is what you after?

Answer (score 1):

The default caption is centered on the page. Using `\centering` will also center the figure.

If you want *to center the caption with the figure* instead, place both within a `minipage` the width of the figure.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\usepackage{showframe} % ONLY to show the margins <<<<<<<,


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) -- (5,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A line I.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{minipage}{5cm} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) -- (5,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{A line II.}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

If you don't know the width of the image in advance, you can measure it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\usepackage{showframe} % ONLY to show the margins <<<<<<<,

\newdimen\imagewidth %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
\maketitle  

\settowidth{\imagewidth}{% measure the image width <<<<<<<<<<
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{minipage}{\the\imagewidth} % use the image width <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) -- (5,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{A line III. If you don't know the width of the image in advance, you can measure it.}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: b]